# Adding js files to nuxt config

Tags: webpack, vue.js, requirejs, config, nuxt.js

Someone designed the front end of my web page and now I am trying to use all the .css and .js files globally for all my pages in nuxtjs. But I am failing to include the files correctly.

This is one of the files I am trying to include: *jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js*. I get this error:

`{
    statusCode: 404, 
    path: '/~/assets/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js',
    message: 'This page could not be found' 
}`

I added the path to the file into my nuxt.js.config, but I can't figure out what I am missing here. Here is my config file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  head: {
    title: 'test-webpage',

    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'test page' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    script: [
      {src: '~/assets/revolution/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js'}
    ]
  },

  build: {
    vendor: ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
    plugins: [
      // set shortcuts as global for bootstrap
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
      })
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Hey Are you able to use jquery plugins in nuxtJS? I'm trying adding bxslider, and I added all CSS nad JS. but the getting bxslider is not a function. even the script is added into the page. I tried calling the plugin from console and it works.. 
I added my count into mounted function.. Any clue is much appreaciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

~ is alias for webpack building. head is used for loading external script, script will not be included in bundled js.

You can move jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js into static and change script to

```
{ src: '/urpathinsidestaticfolder/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js' }
```

Comment: Never thought of considering ~ as an alias in this context. Thank you. Solved my problem.

Comment: @Aldarund, what if my nuxt app is supporting build for several themes and I need to include some scripts for one theme and for other build with a different theme and need different scripts? Does that means that every build will include everything that is located in static folder?

Comment: @31415926 if u add reference to.it into nuxt config then yes. Basically it just adds script tag to that file in your static folder and that's all

Comment: @Aldarund, thx man. I have another question though: If I use head in config to include a static js file it would be imported in the page first and only after that all other scripts like vendors and app... my problem is that my script controls bootstrap theme and requires jquery but jquery is included after my script (I assume bootstrap-vue module does it) How to deal with that?

Comment: @31415926 bootstrap Vue don't use jquery